# Is it possible to left join nested documents in ElasticSearch queries?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

## Context

Assume you have a set of documents for which you have defined a [nested mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/). Also assume that some documents have nested documents and some do not:

#### Document 1

```
{
  "id":1,
  "nested":[
    {
      "x":1
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Document 2

```
{
  "id":2,
  "nested":[
    {
      "x":2
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Document 3

```
{
  "id":3
}
```

---

## Problem

Is there a way to perform the equivalent of the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    r.id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    root r
    LEFT JOIN
    nested n
        ON parent(n) = r
WHERE
    n.x = 1 /* nested condition */
GROUP BY
    r.id
```

Something that comes very close using ElasticSearch's query DSL is:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/nested/type/_search?pretty -d'
{
   "fields":["id"],
   "query":{
       "nested":{
          "query":{
              "constant_score":{
                 "query":{
                    "term":{"x":1}
                 }
              },
              "boost":1.0
           }
        },
        "path":"nested",
        "score_mode":"total"
      }
   }
}'
```

However, since the semantics of [nested queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query/) and [nested filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-filter/) require a document to have [at least one nested document](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/elasticsearch/Jlk7RgkhBG0), **Document 3** would be filtered out here (i.e. "inner-join" semantics).

Is there a workaround / alternate approach to prevent documents from being excluded if they don't have a nested document?

---

## Application

To note above is the condition on the nested documents. Although simple in this example, one can easily imagine situations where score based aggregations based on multiple dynamic conditions can not be precomputed in advance due to a combinatorial explosion.

The main value in the above query is that it includes results that have a score value of "0" and preserves a global document score sort and thus can not be computed using [facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/facets/) or the forthcoming [Aggregation Module](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3300).

---

## Resources

- https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/elasticsearch/cZhIcZ7rxsY
- https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/elasticsearch/Jlk7RgkhBG0
- https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3456
- https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3056

Comment: I'm not super familiar with SQL, so maybe if you describe in words what you want? (Also deleting my answer so the question gets more attention as unanswered.)

Comment: So if I read it correct you want these 2 groups of docs: docs with nested docs where one of the nested docs matches some query **and** docs without any nested docs?

Comment: Can't you just also add a query that will match docs with a missing "nested" field? Am I missing something? [Have a look at this query type from the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/missing-filter/) and see if [you can use it with a bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/)?

Comment: There is no way to specify a missing nested doc, no. The missing filter you cited is works only for simple fields (see my linked resource for ES #3056 to understand why). Because of this, a bool query won't work.

Comment: Yes but you're last doc in the example (doc 3) doesn't have the "nested" field. Why wouldn't a missing filter be able to detect this?

Comment: Simply put, missing filter works on fields, not documents. Nested is actually not a field in the Lucene sense. In order to support the use case you describe, ES would need to store a flag to indicate that the nested documents exist. It doesn't :)

Comment: How about checking for the missing field "nested.x"? (As was suggested in the ES#3056.)

Comment: The recommendation in that issue was for the application to store fields of the nested documents in the root doc for this type of detection. This is precisely what I am trying to avoid since it requires reindexing, application changes etc. Only by using this technique is what you suggest possible.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, don't really know how to help then. Hope someone else can shed some light!